# Opening a Visual Studio 2010 project in 2012 what creates the backup folder and how to control it?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-config, visual-studio-2012

I have an issue.  We are upgrading to VS 2012 at work.  When we open a VS 2010 project Visual Studio converts the project.  This is fine, because VS 2010 can still use the project (yay microsoft).  However, there is a \Backup folder created in the solution directory.  Is this being created as part of the migration?  Is there any way to control it?

The reason I ask is that the process that makes this folder copies web.config files into the folder.  If you then try to build the solution (these are MVC projects), we get a "`It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.`" error.  The cause is that there is a web.config file in a subfolder instead of the root folder.  We did not make and do not want this change, and cannot figure out how to control it. Deleting the Backup\Web.config file fixes the error.  Renaming it from web.config to web.config.bak fixes the problem.

I don't really want to have to personally open and convert every single project, and don't want random people bumping into this problem.  Any idea how to either stop VS from creating the Backup folder, or how to make it create them in the my documents studio folder etc?  I can't find any setting to control this and can't find any good info.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166539.aspx - says that a wizard presents you with options, but I think this happens only if an automatic upgrade isn't possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to control it that I found.  We had to go ahead and run through and convert every project to 2012 and delete the backup folders to prevent any other team from running into it.

Answer (score 1):

By chance, are you using the MvcBuildViews property to pre-compile your views at build time?  If so, this is why you're encountering this (since it does the pre-compile in the same directory, it doesn't filter out any of the files below the project directory).

Note that you will also encounter this issue if you use the Publish feature for this project.  Publish copies the web.config under your intermediate build output directory (by default, obj/) before and after applying web.config transforms.

The good news is that in VS2012, or in VS2010 with the latest Azure SDK installed, pre-compile is now supported for Web Application Projects (including MVC).  These settings are currently in the project properties, under the Package/Publish Web tab.

(this doesn't directly address your question about the Backup folder, but it was too long for a comment.)

Comment: <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews> - yep.  So that's where the issue is coming from.